# Unable to send message to SignalR client in Azure after redeploy

Tags: azure, signalr

I have made a few simple modifications to the [MVC-Chat Sample application](https://github.com/SignalR/Samples/tree/master/BasicChat.Mvc) and have deployed it to Azure running on 2 webworker-instances. Clients can only talk to other clients on the same instance, but that will be solved by using a backplane later.

When I deploy new code to the server (from visual studio), the instances will be upgraded one by one, and all clients will be reconnected first to instance 2 (while instance 1 gets the new code), and then all clients will reconnected to instance 1 while instance 2 is upgraded. (I am not actually changing any code, only re-deploying).

The problem is: After the clients have reconnected, some of them will not be able to receive messages sent to them, but they will receive broadcasts.

Here is my hub code:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private string GetRoleId()
    {
        return RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id;
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string message = String.Format("OnConnected ({0}) {1} - Version: {2}", GetRoleId(), Context.ConnectionId, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);
        Clients.All.newMessage(message);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        Clients.All.newMessage(String.Format("OnDisconnected ({0}) {1} - Version: {2}", GetRoleId(), Context.ConnectionId, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version));
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        Clients.All.newMessage(String.Format("OnReconnected ({0}) {1} - Version: {2}", GetRoleId(), Context.ConnectionId, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version));
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

    public void SendToConnection(string connectionId, string message)
    {
        Clients.Client(connectionId).newMessage(message);
    }
}
```

My Index.cshtml file is also very simple and has few modifications:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var addMessage = function(message) {
        var time = new Date();
        $('#info').prepend('<li>' + time.toUTCString() + ' - ' + message + '</li>');
    };

    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

    chat.client.newMessage = function (message) {
        addMessage('Incomming message: ' + $.connection.hub.transport.name + ' - ' + message);
    };

    var start = function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        addMessage('Before start');
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            addMessage('After start');
        });
    };

    $.connection.hub.stateChanged(function (state) {
        addMessage('State changed (' + state.newState + '). ID: <b>' + $.connection.hub.id + '</b></li>');
    });
    start();
});

</script>

<div id="info"></div>
```

To send a private message in the browser (I use Chrome) to yourself, type this in the developer console:

```
$.connection.chatHub.server.sendToConnection($.connection.hub.id, '<b>Hey!</b>')
```

The "hey" will not appear in about 5-15% of the browsers.

This is what is showing on the javascript console window when a browser that gets "blinded" is reconnected to a server:

```
[15:25:08 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Keep alive has been missed, connection may be dead/slow. jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js:54
[15:25:14 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Keep alive timed out.  Notifying transport that connection has been lost. jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js:54
[15:25:16 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Closing the Websocket jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js:54
[15:25:16 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Clearing hub invocation callbacks with error: Connection started reconnecting before invocation result was received. jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js:54
[15:25:16 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets reconnecting jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js:54
[15:25:16 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://myappname.cloudapp.net/signalr/reconnect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=z-aUiXxW_jcBHDi631xCvrrQLoMtK0jVl3l-dRYcESU01cvkgDzwPfc8GlHk2P9zlmp-4GLwxLYdKzdUJi-vahn0qOGlEnc2Z85p8ecDT1fgTBLI0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&messageId=B%2C14&tid=3' jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js:54
[15:25:25 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js:54
[15:25:25 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'newMessage' on hub 'ChatHub'. jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js:54
[15:25:25 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'newMessage' on hub 'ChatHub'. jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js:54

> $.connection.chatHub.server.sendToConnection($.connection.hub.id, '<b>Hey!</b>')
Object {state: function, always: function, then: function, promise: function, pipe: function…}
```

Any help on solving this bug would be appreciated.

Comment: This could be related to this issue: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2207